# Get duplicated record by using QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

I have a table that contains duplicated records.

I used following code to put the data into a QTableView:

```
QSqlTableModel *dataModel = new QSqlTableModel();
dataModel->setTable("table_name");
dataModel->select();
```

now I wanna to query duplicated records. I use `group by` and having for do that in sql but I haven`t any idea to how do this in qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, I used "setFilter" method as bellow:

```
dataModel = new QSqlTableModel();
dataModel->setTable("CUSTOMER");
QString filter_txt = "id in (select id FROM CUSTOMER GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) >1)" ;
dataModel->setFilter(filter);
dataModel->select();
```